# What is the difference between mapped region and unmapped region in memory space?

Tags: c, heap-memory

I came across the following paragraph in [an article about malloc](http://www.learnme.in/malloc-c/).

> The heap is a continuous (in term of virtual addresses) space of
>   memory with three bounds:a starting point, a maximum limit (managed
>   through sys/ressource.h’s functions getrlimit(2) and setrlimit(2)) and
>   an end point called the break. The break marks the end of the mapped
>   memory space, that is, the part of the virtual address space that has
>   correspondence into real memory.
>
> [image]

I would like to better understand the concept of mapped region and unmapped region.

Comment: Can you attach a link for this article?

Comment: http://www.learnme.in/malloc-c/

Comment: after reading carefully the man pages of `linux`, when using `setrlimit` to change the `data segment` size (which is heap, BSS and initialized data section), it seems that only the `soft limit` - which is the mentioned break point in the question - has any stated affect - e.g. return `ENOMEM`. However I can't find out which role the hardlimit - probably the `rlimit` mentioned in the question, plays.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If memory addresses are 64 bits long, as in many modern computers, you have 18446744073709551616 possible memory addresses. (It depends on the processor architecture how many bits can actually be used, but addresses are stored using 64 bits.) That is more than 17 billion gigabytes, which is probably more memory than your computer actually has. So only some of those 17 billion gigabytes correspond to actual memory. For the rest of the addresses, the memory simply doesn't exist. There is no correspondence between the memory address and a memory location. Those addresses are, therefore, *unmapped*.

That is the simple explanation. In reality, it's a bit more complicated. The memory addresses of your program are not the actual memory addresses of the memory chips, the *physical memory*, in your computer. Instead, it is *virtual memory*. Each process has its own memory space, that is, its own 18446744073709551616 addresses, and the memory addresses that a process uses are translated to physical memory addresses by the computer hardware. So one process may have stored some data at memory address 4711, which is actually stored in a real physical memory chip over here, and another process may have *also* stored some data at memory address 4711, but that is a completely different place, stored in a real physical memory chip over *there*. The process-internal virtual memory addresses are translated, or *mapped*, to actual physical memory, but not all of them. The rest, again, are *unmapped*.

That is, of course, *also* a simplified explanation. You can use more virtual memory than the amount of physical memory in your computer. This is done by *paging*, that is, taking some chunks (called *pages*) of memory not being used right now, and storing them on disk until they are needed again. (This is also called "swapping", even if that term originally meant writing *all* the memory of a process to disk, not just parts of it.)

And to complicate it even further, some modern operating systems such as Linux and MacOS X (but, I am told, not Windows) *overcommit* when they allocate memory. This means that they allocate more memory addresses than can be stored on the computer, even using the disk. For example, my computer here with 32 gigabytes of physical memory, and just 4 gigabytes available for paging out data to disk, can't possibly allow for more than 36 gigabyes of actual, usable, virtual memory. But malloc happily allocates more than one hundred *thousand* gigabytes. It is not until I actually try to store things in all that memory that it is connected to physical memory or disk. But it was part of my virtual memory space, so I would call that too *mapped* memory, even though it wasn't mapped *to* anything.

Comment: Except Windows doesn't overcommit memory. I heard it might do this for thread stacks to allow stack overflow exception handling, but it is totally different from what Linux and other OSes do: `malloc` won't allocate more that your RAM size + page file.

Answer (score 1):

The mapped region in the heap means the virtual memory area that can be mapped together with physical memory. And the unmapped region indicates the unused virtual memory space which does not point to any physical memory.

The boundary between mapped region for the heap and unmapped region is the system break point. As the `malloc()` is used to request some memory, the system break point would be moved to enlarge the mapped region. Linux system offeres `brk()` and `sbrk()` methods to increase and decrease the virtual memory address of the system break point.

Comment: To clarify, in case it was misunderstood, `brk()` decreases the size of the heap and `sbrk()`.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra, Thanks for it.

Comment: ... and `sbrk()` increases it.